# How do I take screenshots on a Samsung Galaxy A3?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, screenshots

I've been trying to take screenshots on my Samsung Galaxy A3 by using both the "home + lock" key combination and the "volume down + lock" key combination, and neither have worked. I don't want to install a Screenshot app on my device.

Does anyone know how to take screenshots on it without downloading any type of Screen Capture, Screen Grab, or Screenshot app?

Comment: Based from [here](http://androidfact.com/how-to-screenshot-samsung-galaxy-a3-a5-and-a7/), it seems you have already used the correct combination "Home + Power". Maybe you didn't hold it for enough time?

Comment: A3 in this Case, not S3...

Answer (score 3):

Try **holding** **Power + Home** together a few moments. it works on all Samsung phones.

Also there's an alternative solution which works only on Samsung and Android 4.0+ phones (has to be activated in `Settings` > `My device [tab]` > `Motions and gestures` > `Palm motion` > `Capture screen`). It works by **Swiping screen with the side of your hand**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Home+Volume Down? My other idea would be that you did not hold the combinations you tried for long enough.